# Using input stream after something wrong was entered in C++

Tags: c++, input

here's my solution to a simple problem of my textbook. Inside of that, I'm trying to use the input stream in order to detect the non-numerical input first, and then check if it's started with the '|' character to terminate the program:

```
    int main()
{
    double n1, n2;
    char Finisher;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter number 1:\n";
        if (std::cin >> n1) {}
        else {
            std::cin >> Finisher;
            if (Finisher == '|') break; //Condition that must lead to program termination.
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(40000,'\n'); //40000: only a big number
        }
        std::cout << "Enter number 2:\n";
        if (std::cin >> n2) {}
        else {
            std::cin >> Finisher;
            if (Finisher == '|') break;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(40000, '\n');
        }

        if (n1 < n2) {
            std::cout << "The smaller value is: " << n1 << " \nThe larger value is: " << n2 << '\n';
            if ((n1 - n2) < 1.0 / 100 && (n1 - n2) > -1.0 / 100) {
                std::cout << "The values are almost equal\n";
            }
        }
        else if(n1>n2){
            std::cout << "The smaller value is: " << n2 << " \nThe larger value is: " << n1 << '\n';
            if ((n1 - n2) < 1.0 / 100 && (n1 - n2) > -1.0 / 100) {
                std::cout << "The values are almost equal\n";
            }
        }
        else { std::cout << "both values are equal\n"; }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Problem is that my "Finisher" char variable seems to be useless, and any non-numerical input (kind of) gets lost! and another fixed character is entered in it regardless of what I've entered, in my case it's always like this: [image]
What's wrong?!
Thank you.

Comment: Just a nit-pick. You may want to do more *"DRY - Do not Repeat Yourself"*.

Comment: Why not read a string (or perhaps [a whole line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)), check if the first character [is a digit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and then attempt to [convert the string to an integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). If not a digit then check for `'|'`, and if not found just discard the input.

Comment: @Yuriy lvaskevych Clearing it to alter the failed state of std::cin, so that again it can accept new entered inputs, and I use the ignore to remove any previous inputs. (their names(clear&ignore) are a bit different from what they do)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, yes you're right, but I wonder why it isn't working in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the clear() up seems to work:

```
    if (std::cin >> n1) {}
    else {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin >> Finisher;
        if (Finisher == '|') break; //Condition that must lead to program termination.
        std::cin.ignore(40000,'\n'); //40000: only a big number
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once the read fails, `cin` is in a state where it won't be able to read anything else until you `clear` it.  You need to call `cin.clear();` before reading in the `Finisher`.

Of course that still puts you in a position where you're reading in a separate character for the `Finisher`.  It would be more elegant to read in a single token and then check if it's a number or a pipe character.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

typedef double number;

number parse_number() {

    static std::string in;
    static std::istringstream stream;
    number ret;

    std::cin >> in;
    stream.clear();
    stream.str(in);

    if (stream >> ret)
        return ret;

    if (in.front() == '|')
        std::exit(0);

    std::ostringstream error;
    error << "Could not parse token, \"" << in << ".\"";
    throw std::runtime_error(error);

}

int main() {

    while (true) {

        const number n1 = parse_number();
        const number n2 = parse_number();

        // Do stuff with the numbers.

    }

}
```